# Which consistency model do I have?

Tags: replication, distributed-computing, distributed

I have implemented a replicated key/value store on top of Redis. I have passive replication in which all write and read requests are forwarded to the leader that always returns the last value written for the key. The system uses quorum. So it works even if there are nodes which are down or with a network partition. In this case, the value in those nodes are not consistent. But this does not prevent the system to return the last most updated value. Do I have an eventual consistency model or a strict one? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that, it is a quorum based system, with one node as a leader. The read and write requests are always forwarded to the leader.

For the sake of simplicity, let's assume that, there are 5 nodes in the system and one of them is a leader. Other 4 nodes are secondaries.

Typically quorum based systems work on consensus protocols. So out of 5 nodes, if 3 of the nodes have the latest value, it is enough to always return the latest value.

**This is how writes should work**

1. Leader first updates the key/value in it's database
2. Forwards the request to remaining 4 nodes, which are secondaries
3. The leader waits for at least 2 of the secondaries to acknowledge that, they have updated the latest key/value in their database. It means out of 5 nodes, at least 3 nodes have the latest updated value.
4. If the leader does not get response from at least 2 of the secondary nodes within the specified time period (request times out), then leader returns failure to client and client needs to retry.

So, the write requests succeeds only if 3 out of 5 nodes have the latest value. At any point, 2 of the nodes may or may not have the latest value and may catch up later.

For the reads, the leader (which has the latest key/value), always returns the response.

**What happens when a leader machine is unable to serve requests, due to some issue? (For e.g. network error)**

1. Typically these systems will have a leader election protocol, when the current leader is unable to serve the requests due to some error.
2. The new leader will be chosen from one of the secondaries, which have the latest updates. So, the newly elected leader should have the latest updated state and should start serving read requests with the latest set of values.

Your system is strictly consistent.